# 1:m and m:m relations: give some information about the associated elements in the backend list

Tags: symfony1, backend

I have created a module using the sfGuardUser model. I'd like to show
in the list of the backend of that module, the groups that a user
belongs to.

I know the backend is not initially prepared for that, but is there
any plugin or any other way to do "easily"?

sf 1.4/propel 1.6

Javier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try creating a getter like getGroupList(), that returns them as a comma-separated list, and adding it as a column to the admin generator?